# Java NIO SocketChannel writing problem

Tags: java, networking, nio

I am using Java NIO's SocketChannel to write : `int n = socketChannel.write(byteBuffer);` Most of the times the data is sent in one or two parts; i.e. if the data could not be sent in one attemmpt, remaining data is retried.

The issue here is, sometimes, the data is not being sent completely in one attempt, rest of the data when tried to send multiple times, it occurs that even after trying several times, not a single character is being written to channel, finally after some time the remaning data is sent. This data may not be large, could be approx 2000 characters.

What could be the cause of such behaviour? Could external factors such as RAM, OS, etc cause the hindarance?

Please help me solve this issue. If any other information is required please let me know.
Thanks

**EDIT:**

Is there a way in NIO SocketChannel, to check, if the channel could be provided with data to write before actual writing. The intention here is, after attempting to write complete data, if some data hasn't been written on channel, before writing the remaining data can we check if the SocketChannel can take any more data; so instead of attempting multiple times fruitlessly, the thread responsible for writing this data could wait or do something else.

Answer (score 2):

TCP/IP is a streaming protocol. There is no guarantee anywhere at any level that the data you send won't be broken up into single-byte segments, or anything in between that and a single segment as you wrote it.

Your expectations are misplaced.

Re your EDIT, `write(`) will return zero when the socket send buffer fills. When you get that, register the channel for `OP_WRITE` and stop the write loop. When you get `OP_WRITE`, deregister it (very important) and continue writing. If `write()` returns zero again, repeat.

Answer (score 0):

While using TCP, we can write over sender side socket channel only until the socket buffers are filled up and not after that. So, in case the receiver is slow in consuming the data, sender side socket buffers fill up and as you mentioned, write() might return zero.

In any case, when there is some data to be sent on the sender side, we should register the SocketChannel with the selector with OP_WRITE as the interested operation and when selector returns the SelectionKey, check key.isWritable() and try writing on that channel.  As mentioned by Nilesh above, don't forget to unregister the OP_WRITE bit with the selector after writing the complete data.

Comment: "when there is some data to be sent on the sender side, we should register the SocketChannel with the selector with OP_WRITE": definitely not. You should just write, and use `OP_WRITE` only when `write()` has returned zero. See my answer. `OP_WRITE` is almost always ready, so there is little point in waiting for it. And it wasn't Nilesh who said anything about deregistering, it was me.